# Discover framebuffer address on unknown architecture?

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, exploit-development

Recently I got running unsigned code through an exploit on an device. Now I would like to discover the framebuffer address so I could write to the screen and output data.

The only way I can imagine to do this is doing a for/while loop and write to every memory address until the screen gets drawed. When I say address I mean pyshicall address.

Is it the good way or are there any other methods to do this? At the moment I'm completely blind since I cannot output anything.

Thanks

Comment: What device is it? What information do you have about it?

Comment: @michalsrb the thing is that I just want to learn how to find framebuffers (and other stuff) addresses so the device doesn't mind. (It's actually a nintendo3ds and addresses are documented but I want to learn to find them by myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see what is on the display or if you can even make the device show picture of your choice, you can guess the data that represent the pixels in the framebuffer. You just need to know the pixel format or try all the typical formats (RGB, BGR, RGBx, BGRx ...). Then you just scan the whole memory for the data you expect to find in framebuffer. Reading is much less destructive than writing and you don't need to observe if the display changed between writes.

Example: Let's say you know that at the moment of execution there is line of pixels containing black, black, white, black and white pixels in this order. Make your exploit scan memory for `000000 000000 FFFFFF 000000 FFFFFF`. If you find a match, you may have found an address inside framebuffer and you can try to write to it to output on display. Obviously the longer the pattern is, the lower chance of false positives.

Comment: Yes, the exploit can access the framebuffer memory (other people has achieved it). The problem is that I don't know the framebuffer address so I cannot write to it; At the moment, the problem is that I'm completely blind, since I can't output to the screen yet I can't read memory and show it in the screen for example.

Comment: So is there anything preventing you in using the method I described? I will make edit to add an example to make it clearer.

Comment: Even if I scan the whole memory, I wouldn't be able to save the dump anywhere, since I can't output to the framebuffer nor I can write to the filesystem yet. There's nothing in the display (well the screen gets freezed when triggering the exploit) and I can't draw any picture. EDIT: I've just seen your edit.. hmm.. as I said the screen gets stuck with some pixels of grey/cream color.. so I could try and search for that pattern maybe

Comment: when I trigger the exploit, there's a blue battery simbol at the top right of the screen. How would I search a pattern for that?

Comment: First you would need to find the exact RGB values used in the symbol. Make screenshot if possible, dig it out of the system image, find it on internet... Depends what your device actually is. Then pick a line of the image and put the RGB values of the pixels next to each other: RGBRGBRGB... And make your exploit search memory for that array of bytes. If it fails, try again with BGRBGRBGR... Or other pixel formats.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, but I also want to know, as I said before, this device has also buttons, so how would I find I/O registers for example?

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. For the buttons you could trace the lines from them to a chip and check its documentation, or make a tool that dumps state of all registers and compare between pressed and released states, or disassemble the firmware and read from there. Reading disassembled firmware is an option for finding the framebuffer address too. In general reverse engineering differs lot case from case - that's the fun of it. :-)

Comment: also, could you show me some code to look for patterns in memory? I tried implementing my own with a pattern someone has gave me but I seems not to work. Code here https://gist.github.com/pedro-javierf/7d4edc033ab07c832777e4a37fa2b287 thanks

Comment: please @michalsrb

Comment: Your example would work, it is just the line 23 is missing one ampersand: Address_of_thing_were_searching_for = &pointer[i]; However I would suggest you to learn general programming first, then you'll be able to write it in more elegant and generic way.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've fixed it, I use now:                             if(pointer[i]==PATTERNBYTE1 && pointer[i+1]==PATTERNBYTE2 pointer[i+2]==PATTERNBYTE3 )
    {
          Address_of_thing_were_searching_for = &pointer[i];
          break;
    }                                                                                                                  Which seems to be better I think? Thanks (and sorry if I'm annoying with so much questions :)

Comment: I've been reading about this for a while. When you said, to create a more elegant and generic code, what did you mean exactly? I want to improve that pattern searcher I did, but it looks great for me at least for small patterns (for larger patterns I think it would take a lot of time). While I know general programming, I can't even imagine what shall i do to improve my code. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like no-mention comments aren't seen, @michalsrb ? Sorry for bumping a post.